# Check nested js object properties in js

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to check the existence of a nested js object property, any way to simplify this code in one line?

```
if(json_root.hasOwnProperty(p1)){
    if(json_root.p1.hasOwnProperty(p2)){
        if(json_root.p1.p2.hasOwnProperty(p3)){
            /**Do your things with json_root.p1.p2.p3*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that `json_root.hasOwnProperty` means that you're not dealing with JSON, but a regular JS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define a `if` statement like this

```
if(json_root.p1 && json_root.p1.p2 && json_root.p1.p2.p3){
    // Here add your code
}
```

The block code of the `if` statement will be executed only when all three condition are valid.